# How do you reformat a date field as MON-YYYY?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-science

I have a date field:

Date: YYYY-MM-DD (eg 2002-05-15) that I want to reformat as a date field to read Mon-YY (eg May-02)

when I run the query

```
select monthname(Date), year(date) from table
```

I obviously get them as two columns. I've tried

```
select to_date(monthname(Date) || ' ' || year(Date)) from table
```

But I get an error. Not sure how to resolve this. I'd like to keep this as a date field if possible.

Answer (score 0):

try this using to_char

```
select column1, column2, to_char(column2 , 'MMMM DD')
from (values (1, to_date('2002-05-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) , (2, to_date('2012-07-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) );
```